# How can I apply a function to subsets of a data.frame without manually creating the subsets?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, apply

Suppose I have a data.frame with,

```
Color Animal Size
Green Frog  2
Red   Frog  5
Green Frog  1
Red   Frog  6
```

If I were to apply the function mean, I would like to get a data.frame that has

```
Color Animal AverageSize
Green Frog 1.5
Red   Frog 5.5
```

Thanks

Comment: `aggregate(Size ~ Color + Animal, data = data, mean)`

Answer (score 3):

The most direct way in base R is to use `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(Size ~ ., mydf, mean)
  Color Animal Size
1 Green   Frog  1.5
2   Red   Frog  5.5
```

There, the "." represents all of the other grouping columns, while "Size" is the column you want to aggregate.

Other options include:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, mean(Size), by = list(Color, Animal)]
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)  
mydf %>%
  group_by(Color, Animal) %>%
  summarise(Size = mean(Size))
```

(Among *many* others.)

Comment: "dplyr" and "data.table" are insanely efficient when you are dealing with the huge data